# Maximal domain of function and its derivative if both have Lebesgue > 0

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure, domain-theory

Consider $f(x) = \ln(x), \sqrt{x}, |x|$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Based on these, I have the following conjecture. Please prove/disprove.

> The maximal domain of $f$ and its derivative differ only by a set of Lebesgue measure zero
>
> if
>
> the maximal domain of $f'(x)$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

Now, the Weierstass function's maximal domain is $\mathbb R$, and its derivative's maximal domain is $\emptyset$, which is zero, so it's okay that the difference, which is $\mathbb R$, does not have Lebesgue measure zero.

To disprove I think of $f(x)$ which has maximal domain $\mathbb R$ and whose derivative is $f'(x)$ has maximal domain $[0,1]$. Could we construct some kind of piecewise weierstrass where $f$ is weierstrass outside $[0,1]$ and then some smooth function like $x^2$ inside $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1):

This is false, even if $f$ is continuous.  (Your construction is "backwards".)

Let $W$ be a [nowhere differentiable continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) (with domain containing $[0,1]$), and set 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} W(0) ,& x \leq 0, \\ W(x) ,& 0 \leq x \leq 1, \\ W(1),& 1 \leq x \end{cases} \text{.}  $$

Then the maximal domain of $f'$ is $(-\infty, 1] \cup [1,\infty)$, which has positive Lebesgue measure.  However, the maximal domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ which differs from the previous set by $(0,1)$ having Lebesgue measure $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\phi(t)=\begin{cases}t^{2}&t>0\\0&t\le 0\end{cases} $$
Note that $\phi'$ exists and is still continuous.

Given two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, we can consider
$$ h(x)=\frac{\phi(x-1)f(x)+\phi(1-x)g(x)}{\phi(x-1)+\phi(1-x)}$$
Note that the denominator is always positive.
Then $h(x)=f(x)$ and $h'(x)=f'(x)$ for $x>1$, whereas $h(x)=g(x)$ and $h'(x)=g'(x)$ for $x<-1$.

Comment: $\phi(x) = \max\{0,x^2\}$ ?

Comment: @BCLC No, $\max\{0,x\cdot |x|\}$. Usually, one glues such stuff together with $e^{-1/t}$, but this simpler $\phi$ suffices here.